# postgres перестал запускаться

Tags: postgresql, администрирование

пропустил момент оплаты vps, серваки выключили. в итоге на самом важном серваке перестал запускаться постгрес. пишет следующие ошибки

```
Apr  7 07:00:54 vm520683 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main...
```

Apr  7 07:00:54

```
 vm520683 postgresql@10-main[474]: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1:
Apr  7 07:00:54 vm520683 postgresql@10-main[474]: no data was returned by command ""/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres" -V"
Apr  7 07:00:54 vm520683 postgresql@10-main[474]: The program "postgres" is needed by pg_ctl but was not found in the
Apr  7 07:00:54 vm520683 postgresql@10-main[474]: same directory as "/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl".
Apr  7 07:00:54 vm520683 postgresql@10-main[474]: Check your installation.
Apr  7 07:00:54 vm520683 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Apr  7 07:00:54 vm520683 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Apr  7 07:00:54 vm520683 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main.
Apr  7 07:00:54 vm520683 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Apr  7 07:00:54 vm520683 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

при попытке переключиться su - postgres
Cannot execute /bin/bash: Permission denied
 хотя раньше такого не было. как это исправить? или если никак, как переустановить постгрес сохраняя базу?

Comment: Полагаю, для начала проверить то, на что оно ругается: Существуют ли `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl` и `/var/run/postgresql/`

Comment: сушествует, проверил

Comment: Тогда вручную попробовать запустить `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf" `

Comment: жалуется на то что нельзя запускать из-под рута. а переключиться на другогго пользователя не получается su - postgres Cannot execute /bin/bash: Permission denied

Comment: Вот что советуют по этому поводу коллеги: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307534/unable-to-su-with-root-bin-bash-permission-denied/779891

Comment: как ни странно, это решило проблему, спасибо